# Serializing Key/Value in WCF JSON

Tags: .net, json, wcf

I have the following code

```
[DataContract]
    public class DeviceParam 
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "param", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<DeviceParam> Param { get; set; }
    }
```

Problem is, that it is produces:

```
{"Key":"Param1","param":[{"Key":"ParamChild1","Value":"1"}]}]
```

I am struggling with this to achieve the desired format:

```
{"Param1": {"ParamChild1" : "1" }}
```

I can't achieve this, since the class contains class of itself. and seems like WCF doesnt like all our modification I am doing in order to achieve it.

What is the best way to implement this with WCF output JSON?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can try this: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx ( http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ )

Comment: but the format you want is not json, I think that you have to create your own formatter

Comment: @DotNeter - why isnt this JSON??

Comment: according to http://www.json.org/ , you have to specify the key and its value, something like : Name : "Mr X", but the format you want doesn't match, you didn't put the key.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your class as follows:

```
[DataContract]
    public class DeviceParam 
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
 [DataContract]
  public class DeviceParamsList
  {
        [DataMember(Name = "param", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<DeviceParam> Param { get; set; }
  }
```

I have not tried it, but this should work